# Deadlock error when running Go CSV filter program with multiple workers

Tags: go

I'm trying to run a Go program that reads a CSV file and applies a filter to each row. The program uses multiple workers to process the rows in parallel.

However, when I run the program with multiple workers, I get the following error:

`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

The error occurs at the following line in my code:

`g.waitGroup.Wait()`

I've tried to close the input channel after distributing the chunks to the workers, as suggested in other similar questions, but it didn't solve the issue.

```go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

type Splitter struct {
    workers        int
    inputFilePath  string
    outputFilePath string
    chunkSize      int64
    workerGroup    []*workerGroup
    mu             sync.Mutex
    cond           *sync.Cond
    finished       bool
}

type workerGroup struct {
    workers    []*worker
    waitGroup  *sync.WaitGroup
    outputChan chan<- chunk
    errorChan  chan error
}

type worker struct {
    id         int
    inputChan  <-chan chunk
    outputChan chan<- chunk
    errorChan  chan<- error
    waitGroup  *sync.WaitGroup
    done       chan bool
}

type chunk struct {
    id     int
    offset int64
    data   []byte
}

func makeChunks(data []byte, chunkSize int64) []chunk {
    var chunks []chunk
    var dataSize = int64(len(data))

    for i := int64(0); i < dataSize; i += chunkSize {
        end := i + chunkSize

        if end > dataSize {
            end = dataSize
        }

        chunks = append(chunks, chunk{
            id:     len(chunks),
            offset: i,
            data:   data[i:end],
        })
    }

    return chunks
}

func NewSplitter(workers int, inputFilePath, outputFilePath string, chunkSize int64) *Splitter {
    s := &Splitter{
        workers:        workers,
        inputFilePath:  inputFilePath,
        outputFilePath: outputFilePath,
        chunkSize:      chunkSize,
        workerGroup:    make([]*workerGroup, 0),
    }

    s.cond = sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{})
    s.finished = false

    return s
}

func (s *Splitter) Split() error {
    inputFile, err := os.Open(s.inputFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to open input file: %v", err)
    }
    defer inputFile.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(inputFile)
    reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1
    reader.TrimLeadingSpace = true

    // Init the output file
    outputFile, err := os.Create(s.outputFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to create output file: %v", err)
    }
    defer outputFile.Close()

    // Init the CSV writer for the output file
    writer := csv.NewWriter(outputFile)
    writer.Comma = ','

    // Init the channels for communicating between workers
    inputChan := make(chan chunk)
    outputChan := make(chan chunk)
    errorChan := make(chan error)

    // Init the worker groups
    for i := 0; i < s.workers; i++ {
        wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(1)

        wgOutputChan := make(chan chunk)
        wgErrorChan := make(chan error)

        workerGroup := &workerGroup{
            workers:    make([]*worker, 0),
            waitGroup:  wg,
            outputChan: wgOutputChan,
            errorChan:  wgErrorChan,
        }

        for j := 0; j < s.workers; j++ {
            id := len(workerGroup.workers)

            wg.Add(1)

            done := make(chan bool)
            w := worker{
                id:         id,
                inputChan:  inputChan,
                outputChan: outputChan,
                errorChan:  errorChan,
                waitGroup:  wg,
                done:       done,
            }

            // Add the worker to the worker group
            workerGroup.workers = append(workerGroup.workers, &w)

            // Start the worker
            go func(w *worker) {
                defer w.waitGroup.Done()

                for {
                    select {
                    case c := <-w.inputChan:
                        // Process the chunk
                        filteredData, err := filterRows(c.data)
                        if err != nil {
                            w.errorChan <- fmt.Errorf("worker %d: failed to filter rows: %v", w.id, err)
                            continue
                        }

                        // Send the filtered chunk to the output channel
                        c.data = filteredData

                        fields := strings.Split(string(c.data), ",")
                        writer.Write(fields)

                    case <-w.done:
                        // Worker is done
                        return
                    }
                }
            }(&w)

            // Add the worker to the wait group
            wg.Add(1)
        }

        // Add the worker group to the splitter
        s.workerGroup = append(s.workerGroup, workerGroup)
    }

    // Start the workers
    for _, g := range s.workerGroup {
        for _, w := range g.workers {
            go func(w *worker) {
                for c := range w.inputChan {
                    data, err := s.applyFilter(c.data)
                    if err != nil {
                        w.errorChan <- err
                    } else {
                        c.data = data
                        w.outputChan <- c
                    }
                }

                w.waitGroup.Done()

                // Signal the main goroutine that the worker has finished
                s.cond.Broadcast()
            }(w)
        }
    }

    // Split the input file into chunks and distribute them to the workers
    chunks := make([]chunk, 0)
    for {
        data := make([]byte, s.chunkSize)
        n, err := inputFile.Read(data)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to read input file: %v", err)
        }
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }
        chunks = append(chunks, makeChunks(data[:n], s.chunkSize)...)
    }

    // Distributed the chunks to the workers
    close(inputChan)

    // Wait for all workers to finish
    for _, g := range s.workerGroup {
        g.waitGroup.Wait()
    }

    // Signal the workers that there are no more chunks to process
    s.mu.Lock()
    s.finished = true
    s.cond.Broadcast()
    s.mu.Unlock()

    // Flush the CSV writer
    writer.Flush()

    return nil
}

func (s *Splitter) applyFilter(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    // Convert the input data to a string
    inputStr := string(data)

    // Parse the input data as CSV
    records, err := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(inputStr)).ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse input CSV: %v", err)
    }

    // Filter the rows based on the filter string
    var filteredRecords [][]string
    for _, record := range records {
        if len(record) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        // Apply the filter to the current record
        filteredData, err := s.filter([]byte(record[0]))
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        if filteredData != nil && strings.Contains(record[0], string(filteredData)) {
            filteredRecords = append(filteredRecords, record)
        }
    }

    // Convert the filtered rows back to CSV
    var filteredBuf bytes.Buffer
    writer := csv.NewWriter(&filteredBuf)
    writer.WriteAll(filteredRecords)
    writer.Flush()

    return filteredBuf.Bytes(), nil
}

func (s *Splitter) filter(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    record, err := decodeRecord(data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to decode record: %v", err)
    }

    // Check if the record matches the filter
    matchesFilter, err := s.matchesFilter(record)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to match filter: %v", err)
    }

    // If the record matches the filter, encode it and return the result
    if matchesFilter {
        encodedRecord, err := encodeRecord(record)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to encode record: %v", err)
        }
        return encodedRecord, nil
    }

    // return nil to indicate that the record should be filtered out
    return nil, nil
}

func (s *Splitter) matchesFilter(record []string) (bool, error) {
    return true, nil
}

func decodeRecord(data []byte) ([]string, error) {
    r := csv.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
    r.FieldsPerRecord = -1
    r.TrimLeadingSpace = true
    return r.Read()
}

func encodeRecord(record []string) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    w := csv.NewWriter(&buf)
    w.Write(record)
    w.Flush()
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}

func filterRows(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    row, err := csv.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data)).Read()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse CSV row: %v", err)
    }

    // e.i (criteria) : keep rows where the second column is an integer greater than 10
    if len(row) >= 2 {
        value, err := strconv.Atoi(row[1])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse integer value: %v", err)
        }
        if value <= 10 {
            return nil, nil
        }
    }

    return data, nil
}

func main() {
    s := NewSplitter(4, "input.csv", "output.csv", 1024)
    if err := s.Split(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me identify the root cause of this error and suggest a solution ?

Comment: Your solution is unnecessarily complicated. In general, you cannot split a CSV file into fixed-sized chunks because there is no guarantee that each chunk will end at a line boundary. You should read the CSV file from a single goroutine, and then distribute each record or a batch of records to different goroutines.